# How to make search/filtered result on the top of Tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, filter, tableview

I am making an information app, it has sections and rows on the table view. There is a searchBar on the top of tableView to filter the name but When i search name, the corresponding name shows as per the array but I want the search result should be on top of the tableView.

I have used some filter in searchbar delegate textDidChange but it is not working what I expect it to be.

For Example: I am searching for "kumar", it is on the 3rd row as per our data. but i want it to be on the top of the table.

**Reason to solve the issue:** If there are lots of rows in the section and if there is a name starts with "Z". It goes all the way down to the tableView

I am very new to swift, Xcode, UIKit.

**Model**:

```
struct Datas {
    var sectionName: String
    var shops: [Detail1]        
}

struct Detail1 {   
    var name: String
    var contact: [String]
    var address: [String]
}
```

**Data**:

```
var data1 = [
    Datas(sectionName: "A", shops: [
        Detail1(name: "raj", contact: ["454545" ], address: ["KNR" ]),
        Detail1(name: "bala", contact: ["878787"], address: ["NGI"]),
        Detail1(name: "raja", contact: ["212121"], address: ["CHN"])
    ]),    
    Datas(sectionName: "B", shops: [
        Detail1(name: "balaji", contact: ["9898898"], address: ["KNR"]),
        Detail1(name: "Siva", contact: ["787878"], address: ["LKD"]),
        Detail1(name: "Kumar", contact: ["2323232"], address: ["MNR"])
    ])
]
```

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       
        filteredData = []
        
        if searchText == "" {
            
            filteredData = data1
            
            tableView.reloadData()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            
        } else {
            
            for word in data1 {
                
                if word.shops.contains(where: {$0.name.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()}) ||
                    word.sectionName.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()
                {
                    filteredData.append(word)
                }
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your question but note that `String` has method `hasPrefix(:_)`

Comment: So you don't want to filter but sort? Meaning you keep all still show all your data, but showing the result at first? It's unclear what you want.  In your sample, if you write `Kumar`, what should be `filteredData` in that case? Do you want to create a fake section "matches" which will be on top?

Comment: @Larme thanks for your reply. Actually i want to filter the data and match result should be on the top of the table. I don't want to create fake section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are only filtering sections while you should also filter the items:

```
filteredData = data1.compactMap { section in
  if section.sectionName.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()) {
     // return whole section
     return section
  }

  let filteredShops = section.shops.filter { $0.name.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()) }

  guard !filteredShops.isEmpty {
     // no match in the given section
     return nil
  }

  // return an updated section with filtered shops
  return Datas(sectionName: section.sectionName, shops: filteredShops)
}
```

Comment: This `extension String { func hasCaseInsensitivePrefix(_ prefix: String, locale: Locale? = .current) -> Bool { range(of: prefix, options: .caseInsensitive, locale: locale)?.lowerBound == self.startIndex } }` might be interesting instead of `lowercased()` each time: `if section.sectionName.hasCaseInsensitivePrefix(searchText) {}`. It's just a suggestion